# Battery draining fast

Tags: battery-life, soft-reboot

I have Samsung Galaxy S2 GT-I9100, I had purchased new battery three days before and charged until it's full, after an hour I found my mobile switched off. I would like to know the how to rectify this issue.

Comment: Are you sure your charger is working?  Also, switch to Airplane mode so your transmitters aren't using battery while you figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

According to the site: http://blog.gsmarena.com/samsung-i9100-galaxy-s-ii-thorough-battery-test-results-are-out-even-better-than-the-galaxy-s/

The battery should last 82 hours, maybe the one you bought may have been used previously, or it already came with problem, this is not normal, it is certainly a problem in the battery itself and not in the cell phone.